# PHP preg_replace backslash

Tags: php, regex

I have double backslashes '\' in my string that needs to be converted into single backslashes '\'. I've tried several combinations and end up with the whole string disappearing when I used echo or more backslashes are added to the string by accident. This regex thing is making me go bonkers...lol...

I tried this amongst other failed attempts:

```
$pattern = '[\\]';
$replacement = '/\/';

?>
<td width="100%">&nbsp;<?php echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement,$q[$i]);?></td>
```

I do apologise if this is a foolish issue and I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: You got pretty wrong information to your question. Do you want to reconsider using `stripslashes()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `stripslashes()` - it does exactly what you're looking for.

```
<td width="100%">&nbsp;<?php echo stripslashes($q[$i]);?></td>
```

Comment: `<?=stripslashes( $q[ $i ] ) ?>` if you have short tags enables. `<?=?>` is shorthand echo, better for templating

Comment: stripslashes will not only convert double backslashes into single backslashes, but remove all single backslashes entirely if they are present. Is this behaviour wanted? The question does not state anything like this.

Answer (score 2):

Use stripslashes instead. Also, in your regex, you are searching for single backslashes and your replacement is incorrect. `\\{2}` should search for double backslashes and `\` should replace them with singles, although I haven't tested this.

Just to explain further, the pattern `[\\]` matches any character in a set comprised of a single backslash. In php, you should also delimit your regex with forward slashes: `/[\\]/`

Your replacement, which is (without delimiters) `\`, is not a regular expression for matching a single backslash. The regex for matching a single backslash is `\\`. Note the escaping. This said, the replacement term needs to be a string, not a regex (with the exception of backreferences).

EDIT: Sven claims below that stripslashes removes all backslashes. This is simply not true, and I will explain why below.

If a string contains 2 backslashes, the first one will be considered an escaping backslash and will be removed. This can be seen at http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/3yn-2ut. The fact that any backslashes remain at all by itself contradicts the claim that stripslashes removes all backslashes.

Just to clarify, this string declaration is invalid: `$x = "\";`, since the backslash escapes the second quote. This string `"\\"` contains **one** backslash. In the process of unquoting this string, this backslash will be removed. This `"\\\\"` string contains **two** backslashes. When unquoting, the first will be considered an escaping backslash, and will be removed.

Comment: Regarding `stripslashes()` see my comment to user kmkf. Regarding preg delimiters, you do not need slashes, anything will work. If slashes are inconvenient, e.g. because they are used in the pattern as a normal character and would need to be escaped then, hash signs "#", exclamation marks "!" etc. may be used.

Comment: @Sven I know that you can use other characters for delimiters. Nowhere in my answer have I implied otherwise. My personal preference is forward slashes, and using them as delimiters is in no way inconvenient here, since we are not dealing with replacement of forward slashes.

Comment: @Sven Additionally, you are wrong about stripslashes removing all backslashes. stripslashes removes all **escaping** backslashes. Whether or not magic quotes is enabled will affect how many backslashes are considered escaping backslashes.

Comment: That is not what the doc says. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Sven [Here](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/1wt-rqb) is an example. The 4 backslashes in my example denote a string containing 2 backslashes. When stripslashes is passed this string, it returns a string with the escaping backslash removed.

Comment: I have edited your example to show that single backslashes are removed. Convinced?

Comment: @Sven let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18375/discussion-between-asad-and-sven)

Answer (score 2):

Use preg_replace to turn double backslash into single backslash:

```
preg_replace('/\\\\{2}/', '\\', $str)
```

- The `\` in the first parameter needs to be escaped twice, once for `string` and once more for `regex`, just like CodeAngry says.
- In the second parameter it only gets excaped once for `string`.

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Never use a regular expression if the string you are looking for is constant, as is the case with "Every instance of double backslash".

Use `str_replace()` for this task. It is a very easy function that replaces every occurance of a string with another.

In your case: `str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $var)`.

The double backslash actually translates into four backslashed, because inside any quotes (single or double), a single backslash is the start of an escape sequence for the following character. If you want one literal backslash, you have to write two of them. You want two backslashes, you have to write four of them.

I do not like the suggestion of `stripslashes()`. This will of course "decode" your double backslash into one single backslash. But it will also remove all single backslashes in the whole string. If there were none - fine, otherwise things will fail now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '[\\]'; // wrong
$pattern = '[\\\\]'; // right
```

escape \ as \\ and escape \\ as \\\\ because \\] means escaped ].

Comment: `[\\\\]` would still match single backslashes, wouldn't it? It is the regular expression which matches a single character that belongs to the set comprised of two backslashes.

Comment: Each pair of backslashes is only one in a PHP string. So two in RegExp means 4. You need to escape \ as they are used to escape \' in' in single quoted string. Try it.

Comment: I understand that. Perhaps this [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/sggr4UahNs) will explain what I mean?

Comment: `'/[\\\\]/'` is a character class with two characters inside: Backslash and Backslash. This class will find one single backslash, because doubling a character inside a class does not change it, it is a set of "these characters may occur here". What you really mean is `'/\\\\/'` as a regex. This will match two backslashes.

Comment: @Sven \\\\ goes like this: set of 4 becomes set of 2 after PHP processes the string. Set of 2 prevents the \] from being interpreted as an escaped ]. \\] will not escape the ] while \] will. Even in single quote string, slashes should be escaped. Escape 1 for php and 2 for regexp. Right?

Comment: Ok, once more: `"[\\\\]"` in the code becomes `[\\]` in memory. Then the preg parser comes along and sees: Opening square bracket, start of class. Backslash: Something is escaped. Backslash: This one is escaped. Closing square bracket: End of class. So I was wrong with two backslashes in the class, but you were also wrong with escaping the closing bracket. This completely shows to not use regular expressions for simple string replacements. :)

Comment: @Sven I never tested the RegExp for what he needed. I just warned him that he escapes the closing square bracket if he uses that form. I was less wrong :) After patter goes in memory and \ are reduced by half we get: [\] - broken regexp as we ascape the ] ; [\\] valid regexp as we don't escape the ] :)

Comment: avoid backslash hell:  hex-code for backslash is 5C: `$pattern = '#\x5c\x5c#';` will match two adjacent backslashes.

Answer (score -2):

Use htmlentities function to convert your slashes to html entities then using str_replace or preg_match to change them with new entity

Comment: Backslashes do not have a html entity defined.